# How in the C language to pull the first character out of the string?

Tags: c

I need an analog of the charat function in java, which can be used in C language. I searched the Internet and read the documentation for the language, but I did not find this function. I use char *argv[].
 pass arguments to the program, and then from each argument I need to print the first character, how can this be implemented?

Comment: try: `argv[1][0]` , `arg[2][0]`, `arg[3][0]`........... so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth it for you to look into how strings are "handled" in C.
strings are really just an array of chars in c.

Where argv[1] will give you the second argument, argv[1][0] will give you the first character of the second argument.

Just loop from there, ie:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i ++){
        printf("%c\n",argv[i][0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sorry i don't have a compiler handy to check my syntax.
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to dissect `char *argv[]` step by step:-

```
char *argv[] is an array of character pointers  
argv[i]      is the ith element in the array i.e a char*  
*(argv[i]+0) i.e argv[i][0] is the first character of the ith element of the array
```

I guess you get the idea by now..

Comment: Yes Thanks Now everything is clear